# How to save a python array with numbers of strings to a file that is human readable

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how to save the array created in this question's answer (by Paul) to a text file.

[How do I print an aligned numpy array with (text) row and column labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048299/how-do-i-print-an-aligned-numpy-array-with-text-row-and-column-labels/5048479#5048479)

The details are:

```
a = np.random.rand(5,4)
x = np.array('col1 col2 col3 col4'.split())
y = np.array('row1 row2 row3 row4 row5'.split())
b = numpy.zeros((6,5),object)
b[1:,1:]=a
b[0,1:]=x
b[1:,0]=y
b[0,0]=''
printer = np.vectorize(lambda x:'{0:5}'.format(x,))
print printer(b).astype(object)

[[     col1 col2 col3 col4]
 [row1 0.95 0.71 0.03 0.56]
 [row2 0.56 0.46 0.35 0.90]
 [row3 0.24 0.08 0.29 0.40]
 [row4 0.90 0.44 0.69 0.48]
 [row5 0.27 0.10 0.62 0.04]]
```

Comment: Please do not use HTML to format code but simply select it and click the `{}` button or indent it manually with 4 spaces. This ensures proper display and syntax highlighting - right now someone who would usually fix your formatting is likely to not do it because he'd have to remove all the HTML linebreaks on his own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like to use the repr() and .rjust() functionality of writelines.  So let's say I have a Matrix 'mat' (i.e. an ndarray) where A.shape = (10,2), and would like certain formatting and rounding, I can get a decent, adjusted output by using the following:

```
mat = numpy.random.rand(10,10)
f = open('myFile','a')
m,n = mat.shape
for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        f.writelines(repr(round(mat[i,j],4)).rjust(7))
f.writelines('\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: That works but the first column is text so I had to add and if...else statement to format them differently. I also had to change the append "a" file setting to write as I almost missed the correct results at the end of the incorrect results. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about the if statement and the append, great catch.  I also did a poor job of choosing "magic numbers" for the round() and rjust() and could have done that better.  Thanks so much for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The way you go about it depends on how you intend to access it.  Since you want it human readable, the easy solution is to print it to a file.  That does make it more difficult to restore from the file though.

```
f = open(Filename, 'w')
f.write(str(printer(b).astype(object)))
f.flush()
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. Each line is wrapped. Is there a setting to remove the wrapping? Also, the cells with text are cut off.